# convert strings to datetime

Tags: string, datetime

I have asp.net application and am using Entity Framework to connect it with the database. in this application, I have a textbox to get the date(am using calender css style here), and its in the string type.

I have a column in my database and its in Date Time format, I need to compare the textbox value with the date column in my database, for this I just used the code as

```
public StudentAttendances(string date)
    {
        if (date != "")
        {
            DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(date);

            foreach (DataAccess.StudentAttendance studentAttendance in buDataEntities.StudentAttendances.Where(s => s.Date == date1))
            {
                this.Add(new StudentAttendance(studentAttendance.StudentId));
            }
        }
    }
```

for example if I select a date in my textbox(the format is 04/05/2012) and when I compare this with the database its not showing any data, but actually some datas are there for this date.

Comment: What database and what programing language are you using ?

Comment: Very unclear question. Where do you fetch your date from database server and what kind of variable do you store it in? What does the line where you compare the dates look like? Can you show us some more code?

Comment: I modified the question, kindly check it and clarify my doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is comparing both day and time (hours, minutes etc will have to match). Try comparing just the day part like this:

```
buDataEntities.StudentAttendances.Where(s => s.Date.Subtract(date1).Days == 0)
```

I also think that you should specify what format the input date from the users is in.
04/05/2012 may mean both 4th April or 5th of May depending on your computers regional setting.
Here is an example (below) for converting a date string in American format to DateTime object:

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(date, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

your ask is very limited, but try to see this

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether the following works for you:

```
public StudentAttendances(string date)
{
    if (date != "")
    {
        // please see the change from your given code
        DateTime date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy",
                                   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        foreach (DataAccess.StudentAttendance studentAttendance in buDataEntities.StudentAttendances.Where(s => s.Date == date1))
        {
            this.Add(new StudentAttendance(studentAttendance.StudentId));
        }
    }
}
```